# How to use multi-language in text input Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to build Kivy application in which I need to have a text input field with multiple languages. I have a ComboBox or the kivy drop down to select the language and set the appropriate .ttf file. But the text appearing is not the correct transliteration of the English text input.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a codec library. It will convert text of different character sets to be compatible with others.